# JavaScript to add an item to the cart is broken

Tags: javascript, magento

I've got a button, which is part of the provided code in my Magento theme, and according to the date/time stamp, I haven't inadvertantly edited it. I'm sure that it was working at some point, but a glance back into my source control over the last week, and I can't seem to track down where things went wrong.

Here is the button HTML:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

... but when I click on it nothing happens. Seems pretty straight forward, except I can't see if/where there is a typo, etc. So, I check Firebug and I see the following error:

[image]

However, when I go to "View page source", the script is indeed in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Does your Magento theme use multiple JavaScript libraries (e.g. jQuery and prototype.js)? I'd suggest removing the link to jQuery and any additional plugins/scripts, check if the issue still occurs, then use jQuery's [noConflict() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to avoid conflicts with prototype.js and include those scripts again if all is well at that point.

Comment: Is your script in the <head> section>

Comment: It's not in the head section. It's in the middle of the page.

Comment: @Nick - removing JQuery worked to restore functionality of the "Add to cart" button. I'm trying the 'noConflict()' deal now.

Comment: @Nick - this is definitely it. I played around with the noConflict() option. Unfortunately, when using noConflict, the plugin I've added (jPlayer) breaks. It's like I can have one or the other. I'm trying to figure out the best way to integrate them.

Comment: Don't forget to substitute the $ signs in your jPlayer code for the word 'jQuery'. i.e. Call `jQuery.noConflict()` immediately after including jQuery, then replace any `$("#jpId").jPlayer()` calls with `jQuery("#jpId").jPlayer()`. Your `productAddToCartForm()` code can go anywhere after the `noConflict()` declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` variable is in conflict with other JavaScript libraries being used. Removing the inclusion of the jQuery library should bring back the other functionality, in order to prove that is the problem.

In order to fix it, either rewrite the jPlayer code (replacing `$` with `jQuery`), or try using the `jQuery.noConflict()` function.

I.e., this:
`$(document).ready(function(){` ...

... becomes that:
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){` ...

More details can be found in the [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) documentation.

In this particular example in my question above, I solved it by using `noConflict()` in the following way:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {      
      jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: jQuery('#jquery_jplayer').attr('media_file')
      });
    },
    swfPath: "/js/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the productAddToCartForm is not getting instantiated

You could try to use firebug to create a VarienForm object from the console to see if its returning an object.

var tmpobj = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form')

and see what what gets created in tmpobj

And also the .bind after both functions does not seems ok. You are not using an inmediate function and besides does functions are not returning anything.

A more complete example would be easier to fix.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what the first line of the script is doing. That doesn't seem to be the issue in this case.

Comment: can u try to stop the execution with a breakpoint after submit gets assigned, and then inspect the productAddToCartForm object to see if does have a method called submit that takes one argument?, because that's what the onclick is trying to call

Comment: Nick's comment under the original question is the issue. There's a conflict between JQuery and the cart component. When I remove JQuery for testing, the cart comes back to life.

Comment: well that's problably because VarienForm tries to use $ to call its library and jquery also uses that symbol, you'll have to include jquery with noConflict, i think someone already talked about that.

Comment: Yup, that's the issue. Unfortunately noConflict() breaks my jPlayer playback (which is the reason jQuery is being included in the first place). I'm working through some options right now.

Comment: well there is a hack you could try and that is create your own $ function which then tries to apply the value passed trough it to one of the two.